# put a for loop inside a echo statement

Tags: php, for-loop, echo

I want to put a for loop inside the echo but I can´t,  is this possible?

```
<?php
 $limite_may=2014;
 $limite_inf=1914;
 echo"
    <select name='anio_a1' class='select' id='anio_a1'>
    <option selected='selected' value='--'>year</option>".
       for($i=$limite_may; $i>$limite_inf; $i--){
       echo $i;
       }.           
       "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: You don't need a for loop inside the echo. Split the echo in two and put the loop at the desired place in the middle.

Comment: Jon is right. just replace the first period with a semicolon and replace the 2nd period with "echo "

Comment: Awesome engineering !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to `echo` inside a for loop, not put a for loop in the echo. We go though and echo out each item as an `<option>` with the value `$i`.

```
...
echo "<select name='anio_a1' class='select' id='anio_a1'>";
for($i = $limite_may; $i>$limite_inf; $i--) {
    echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
}
?>
echo "</select>";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$limite_may=2014;
$limite_inf=1914;
echo "<select name='anio_a1' class='select' id='anio_a1'>";
for($i=$limite_may; $i>$limite_inf; $i--){
    echo "<option value='--'>".$i."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your HTML from your PHP code blocks entirely, like this:

```
<?php
     $limite_may=2014;
     $limite_inf=1914;
?>
<select name='anio_a1' class='select' id='anio_a1'>
<?php

    for($i=$limite_may; $i>$limite_inf; $i--){
        ?>
        <option value='<?php echo $i; ?>'><?php echo $i; ?></option>
        <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

If your selected value is stored in a variable named `$selected` (for example) you can use it like this (HTML5):

```
<option<?php echo $i==$selected ? ' selected' : ''; ?> value='<?php echo $i; ?>'><?php echo $i; ?></option>
```

or like this (XHTML):

```
<option<?php echo $i==$selected ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?> value='<?php echo $i; ?>'><?php echo $i; ?></option>
```